# Stackdriver - Unable to create subgroup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

When I try to create a subgroup of a group it sends me to the subgroup creation page but when I finish creating it, it turns out to have just created a normal Group and doesn't show up as a subgroup for the parent group.

I am currently on the free 30 day trial (couldn't find if that limited me)